# Remove indentation on some toc items

Tags: table-of-contents

I have some sections without a number, but which I would like to have with a dotted line. However they automatically get the indentation of a section as that is globally defined with `\tableofcontents`. Is it possible to remove the indentation before the "1 Context" but uphold the indentation afterwards?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
...

\begin{document}

\section*{Inhoudsopgave}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother

\section*{Inleiding}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Inleiding}%
... 
text 
...
\chapter{Context}
...
\end{document}
```

[image: toc]

Comment: `\usepackage{tocloft}` will give a clue. Whether this will work with one of the `\cftXindent` commands depends on the class, however. Please post a working example, not just a screen shot of the desired outcome

Comment: I haven't tried tocloft yet as I pressumed this was possible without extra packages. I have added my example which generates this.

Comment: Hm, why `\@starttoc{toc}` instead of `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: The title was too big, but I fixed it now and reapplied "\tableofcontents"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The length `\cftsecindent` with `tocloft` package controls the indentation of sections. It should be written to the `ToC` itself and wrapping a group around this, so `\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup....}...\addtocontent{toc}{\endgroup}` in order to limits its range only to the first unnumbered sections.

The `\protect` commands are necessary since `\setlength` is fragile and will break during the writing process.

Side remark: The `tocloft` package defines a lot of `\cftX....` commands where `X` is either `chap`, `sec`, `subsec` etc. Please see the documentation of `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\setlength{\protect\cftsecindent}{-\leftmargin}}
\section*{Inleiding}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Inleiding}%

\section*{Voorword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Voorword}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

\clearpage

\chapter{Context}
\section{Het bedrijf}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1213904: You're welcome! Happy TeXing.